# Toggle image on hover of thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, image, toggle, show

please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/e47xq/2/

I want to show the large image of the thumbnail when the uses hovers on the thumbnail. Below is my starting point. Any suggestions how to do this? In my final version there will be possible 20 thumbnails so I need the code to be as concise as possible.

```
$(".thumnails").on("mouseover mouseout", "a", function () {
$('#').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

`$(this).attr('href')` get current a tag `href` attribute.

```
$(".thumnails").on("mouseover mouseout", "a", function () {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).toggle();
});
```

and

set 2nd image id to `image-2`

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FZVa5/)</kbd>

Id must be unique. Don't use same id for multiple elements.

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178)

Comment: Thanks for noticing my mistake, I know to only use unique id's, it was a copying error.

Comment: @angela you want to do it `title` attribute  --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/e47xq/3/

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably not the best overall solution, but given what you have, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e47xq/1/

Use `$(this).attr('href')` on the anchor element to retrieve the selector you need.

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to link the thumbnail to the title attribute of the large image instead of the id?