# How to change an image's src when hovering on a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change an image's `src` when hovering on a `<p>` using jQuery, like the News section in the home page of http://mdpoison.com/. (Try hovering on the topics of "Did you know?")

I see in this page code that there the html is like:

```
<p data-val="/media/SOP/mdpoisoncom/homepage/didyouknow/CarbonMonoxideDidYouKnow.jpg" class="">
  Families can help prevent poison-related injuries this winter by following the MPC’s <a href="http://mdpoison.com/media/SOP/mdpoisoncom/education/pdf/WinterPoisonSafety_2014.pdf">winter poison safety tips</a>.
</p>
```

and when you hover on it, it adds a class called `dky-active`. I don't know how to add this class and to switch a new `src` with jQuery.

I see codes like this:

```
$('ul.small img').hover(function ()
{
  $('.inner img').attr('src' ,$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

but that's of no use in my case because I want to toggle images.

Comment: A quick search throws up this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494169/toggle-image-on-hover-of-thumbnails and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556856/toggle-image-on-hover-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <p data-img="http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/images_blogs/rawfile/2013/11/offset_WaterHouseMarineImages_62652-2-660x440.jpg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p data-img="http://imageswiki.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/images-Photoshop-Image-of-the-horse-053857-.jpg">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
</div>
<div class="picture">
    <img src="" id="picture" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('p').mouseover(function () {
   $('#picture').attr('src', $(this).data('img'));
});
```

**[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r77okbmw/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could use the css [**~ selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) for this.

By using this, it avoids using javascript and pushes it all onto a css selector instead:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
.myImg {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300); /*original placeholder*/
}
.wrapper .ptag1:hover ~.myImg {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/200); /*first paragraph hovered*/
}
.wrapper .ptag2:hover ~.myImg {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300); /*second paragraph hovered*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="ptag1">I'm a paragraph. Hover Me!!</p>
  <p class="ptag2">I'm a paragraph. Hover Me too!!</p>
  <div class="myImg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('p').on('mouseover',function(){
  
  $('img').attr('src',"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2");
  
  });
$('p').on('mouseout',function(){
  
  $('img').attr('src',"http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1");
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Hover me to change the image</p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1" width="200" height="200">
```